# Center a Node Vertically TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, nodes

I'm using TikZ to create the following drawing:

[image: drawing]

So far so good, but now I'd like to center the node with the gray background vertically. Here's its code:

```
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{2pt}
\draw[xshift=-3cm,yshift=(current bound box.center)]
  node[align=left,right,rounded corners,fill=black!10,inner sep=1ex]
  {$
    \left\{
      \begin{array}{llc}
        h &=& \overline{AF}\\
        l &=& \overline{BF}\\
        l'&=& \overline{AB}\\
        d &=& \overline{CE}
      \end{array}
    \right.
  $};
```

It's being pushed to the left by `xshift`, thus I could equally use `yshift` with a measure to center it. However, is it possible to do it dynamically (by retrieving the bounding box height)? That's, if the drawing grows, it will remain centered.

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. While code snippets are useful in analysis, MWE will save time for those who try to find a solution for you.

Comment: @HarishKumar Certainly, sorry for that and thanks. I thought it would be simple enough and the node code would be only part needed, but that's no excuse…

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the `positioning` library and then use the `left=of <node identifier>` for positioning the node containing the array; I added some more files to the array to see the effect:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{2pt}
\node[draw,fill,circle,inner sep=1pt,label=right:$C$] at (3,0) (c) {};
\node[align=left,rounded corners,fill=black!10,inner sep=1ex,left=of c]
  {$
    \left\{
      \begin{array}{llc}
        h &=& \overline{AF}\\
        l &=& \overline{BF}\\
        l'&=& \overline{AB}\\
        d &=& \overline{CE}\\
        h &=& \overline{AF}\\
        l &=& \overline{BF}\\
        h &=& \overline{AF}\\
        l &=& \overline{BF}\\
      \end{array}
    \right.
  $};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

More generally (as **Caramdir** has suggested), you can use `left=of current bounding box.center`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{2pt}
\node[draw,fill,circle,inner sep=1pt,label=right:$C$] at (3,0) (c) {};
\node[align=left,rounded corners,fill=black!10,inner sep=1ex,left=of current bounding box.center]
  {$
    \left\{
      \begin{array}{llc}
        h &=& \overline{AF}\\
        l &=& \overline{BF}\\
        l'&=& \overline{AB}\\
        d &=& \overline{CE}\\
        h &=& \overline{AF}\\
        l &=& \overline{BF}\\
        h &=& \overline{AF}\\
        l &=& \overline{BF}\\
      \end{array}
    \right.
  $};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: More generally, `left= of current bound box.west` is I think what the OP wants.

Comment: @Caramdir yes, I'll add this to my answer.

Comment: Thanks Mr. Medina, I still learning how to use TikZ properly and every advice such as about the `positioning` library (which was new to me) is quite valuable. Also thanks @Caramdir for the second solution!

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to avoid the positioning library :

1) Align with (C)

```
 \node[align=left,rounded corners,
       fill=black!10,inner sep=1ex,anchor=east] at ([xshift=-2cm]c) {....
```

2) Align with (current bounding box)

```
  \node[align=left,rounded corners,fill=black!10,
        inner sep=1ex,anchor=east] at (current bounding box.west) {...
```